# Keyboard Shortcut to select Table Bounding Box - InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, shortcuts, tables

I've been searching online for the keyboard shortcut to select a table's bounding box (container, if you will) but have found nothing. With a text box, if you are editing text within the said text box you can hit the escape key to select it's bounding box. When editing text in a table cell, the escape key shortcut selects the cell. I'm looking for a shortcut to select the table bounding box so I don't have to use my mouse to change from the Type Tool to the Selection Tool when I'm working with a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pres <kbd>Esc</kbd> to select the cell and then <kbd>V</kbd> to change the Text tool to the Selection tool.

Actually when you hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> while editing a text in a text frame, you are doing exactly the same, changing the Text tool to the Selection tool.

Comment: I feel a little stupid. I assumed it was selecting all the text in the cell so never tried to hit a key. It does indeed to the exact same thing. Thanks for your help!